# ¿Cómo hacer un LEFT JOIN en LinQ C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join

tengo una duda que no se hasta este punto como puedo implementar un JOIN que me devuelva lo siguiente.

Tengo 2 tablas de las cuales la tabla:
[image: ChecklistUsuarios] es la principal tabla con la que realizo los JOIN correspondientes a otras tablas para obtener la información relacionada, sin embargo, si existe un registro cuyo ID de la columna iIdPersonalSalida no existe (NULL) debo mostrar el registro con la información que tiene, es decir, con un LEFT JOIN.

He intentado realizarlo de varias maneras y no logro coincidir para que me devuelva todos los registros auque no tengas un iIdPersonalSalida

¿Cómo podria implementar esta sentencia LinQ?

Hasta ahora, esto es lo que tengo de la sentencia LinQ:

```
from checklist in context.ChecklistUsuarios
join personal_salida in context.PersonalAplicacion on checklist.iIdPersonalSalida equals personal_salida.iIdPersonalAplicacion into data_A from data_B in data_A.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

He probado haciendolo en SQL normal y si funciona con un LEFT JOIN pero en LinQ no me arroja mas que los registros que coincidan, si es null no lo retorna cuando debería de retornarlo.

```
FROM [ControlEquipos].[dbo].[ChecklistUsuarios] AS checklist
LEFT JOIN [ControlEquipos].[dbo].PersonalAplicacion AS personal_salida ON checklist.iIdPersonalSalida = personal_salida.iIdPersonalAplicacion
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto debería darte un left join

```
from checklist in context.ChecklistUsuarios
from personal_salida in context.PersonalAplicacion.Where(x => checklist.iIdPersonalSalida == x.iIdPersonalAplicacion).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { checklist , personal_salida  } // Esto debes cambiarlo según lo que quieras devolver
```